# JQUERY Form Not Submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script to prevent a form unless at least one of the three values is not equal to 0. The check works but when i change the value to not equal 0 the submit button is still disabled and the form will not submit. Any help is appreciated.

```
$("input[type='submit']").click(function(e){
 // Stop the form submitting
   e.preventDefault();

  if($("input[name='satscore']").val() != '0' || $("input[name='actscore']").val() != '0' || $("input[name='gpascore']").val() != '0'){
return true;
  }else{
// Tell the user the input is invalid
alert('Please select an option');
 }
})
```

Comment: You need to explain what is your **input type**, and maybe you could show your html code.

Answer (score 0):

Put the e.preventDefault(); inside the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You prevented the click.

Replace

```
return true;
```

With

```
$("input[type='submit']").submit();
```